# VBA to put multiple columns with two rows in Excel on their own rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a sheet that looks like this:

```
   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |
----------------------------------------
     62| Value1| Value2|       |       |
    345| Value3| Value4| Value5| Value6|
     17| Value7| Value0|       |       |
    111| Value8| Value9| ValueA|ValueC |
```

I'd like to transform it to this (A is standar, next two cells - B&C, D&E,..):

```
   A   |   B   | C    |
-----------------------
     62| Value1|Value2|
    345| Value3|Value4|
    345| Value5|Value6|
     17| Value7|Value0|
    111| Value8|Value9|
    111| ValueA|ValueC|
```

Currently I'm using the below macro by convert only one row but I want it with two cell value.

```
Sub Transform()

Dim rowStr As String
Dim rowIndex As Integer

rowIndex = 1

For Each Cell In Sheet1.Range("A1:E5")
    If Cell.Column = 1 Then
        rowStr = Cell.Value
    ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Cell.Value) Then
        Sheet2.Cells(rowIndex, 1) = rowStr
        Sheet2.Cells(rowIndex, 2) = Cell.Value
        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this.

```
Sub Transform_2()

Dim c As Range
Dim rngFirstCol As Range
Dim rowIndex As Long
Dim j As Long

rowIndex = 1
Set rngFirstCol = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1), Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown))
For Each c In rngFirstCol
  For j = 0 To rngFirstCol.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count - 2 Step 2
    If c.Offset(, j + 1).Value <> "" Or c.Offset(, j + 2).Value <> "" Then
      Sheet2.Cells(rowIndex, 1).Value = c.Value
      Sheet2.Cells(rowIndex, 2).Resize(1, 2).Value = c.Offset(, j + 1).Resize(1, 2).Value
      rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
    End If
  Next
Next

End Sub
```

It automatically decides how many rows does your data table have. If you want, you can set it yourself by changing

`Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1), Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown))`

to a *column reference* like

`Sheet1.Range("A1:A6")`

Comment: Thanks, its perfectly woking but i see the macro is picking only the first 4 column and then it moves to next row but we have data more than 50 column in a row which keep changing

Comment: i guess if we loop the offset with the column index, it should work ?

Comment: It would. The second `If` condition then would be removed and, for example, if you start from `j = 0`, every `Offset` would become something like `c.Offset(, j + 1)`. Also, you would have `Step 2`. Just need to indicate where to stop looping.

Comment: 'we have data more than 50 column in a row which keep changing' this is information that goes into the question

Comment: I have slightly changed the code to account for this.

Comment: Great... it works perfectly now..